# Fire scroll event on any scrollTop assignment

Tags: javascript, html

In my code i assign an integer value to `myHTMLScrollBarEl.scrollTop` property and expect scroll event to fire. However when the value is equal to the existing one nothing happens.

How can i force scroll event to fire every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger scroll event use `$(window).scroll();` after your codes. Setting scroll position using the code does not triggers the scroll event itself.

for triggering scroll event using pure Javascript ([reference](https://plainjs.com/javascript/events/trigger-an-event-11/)):

```
function triggerEvent(el, type){
   if ('createEvent' in document) {
        // modern browsers, IE9+
        var e = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        e.initEvent(type, false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(e);
    } else {
        // IE 8
        var e = document.createEventObject();
        e.eventType = type;
        el.fireEvent('on'+e.eventType, e);
    }
}

//An finally fire it
triggerEvent(window, 'scroll');
```

Comment: i don't use jQuery in my project, vanilla javascript only

Comment: Ok. I added the triggering method using pure Javascript.

Comment: it is good, however i would use `setTimeout(el.dispatchEvent(e))` to put it into another task just like the ordinary event.

Answer (score 0):

Using `document.createEvent` plus `event.initEvent` as described in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47146892/6928824) is deprecated as stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/initEvent).

As of [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) the preferred way to create and fire an event instance is now

```
var scrollEvent = new Event('scroll', {
    bubbles: true,
    cancelable: false,
    composed: false,
});
myHTMLScrollBarEl.dispatchEvent(scrollEvent)
```